# Laravel & Angular: how to return entire public directory for single page app dependencies

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, dependencies

I have found plenty of tutorials explaining how to use Laravel and Angular together for a single page app. Each seems to have it's own method of adjusting the public directory, or forwarding a file using the File helper.

Right now I have changed my public path in my `config/view.php`. In my routes file I have...

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return View::make('index');
});
```

This works. It forwards to my index.php. However my problem is that I have a ton of scripts and style sheets called in that file (it was originally a .html, not .php). It fails to import those scripts and styles. I cannot seem to find a good solution to this.

I would like to simply returning an entire directory from Laravel. This would be my public directory, containing all my styles and scripts needed for my Angular app.

Is this possible? It seems like this would be a good solution, but I can't seem to find a way to make it happen.

Sorry if this is a simple problem.

Comment: Include your scripts in that view and as for the php file. Put that all inside your controller

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using laravel 4.x so to call assets just use asset function.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls